# How to create listbox dynamically in c# .it should be like intellisense

Tags: c#

How to create listbox dynamically in c# .it should be like intellisense.

Comment: You will have to be more specific: ASP.NET, WinForms, something else? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: What do you mean with creating listbox like intellisense?

Comment: I think he might be referring to auto suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autocompletetype.aspx) guide to what i think you want.

There is another way with auto suggest + textboxes [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34785-create-an-autocomplete-textbox-control-in-c%23/) on dreamincode.net has a pretty detailed walk through.